# Creating a eclipse plug-in using with a WizardPage

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to create a plug-in for eclipse consisting of a Wizard for creating a new file.

In the documentation I read about the [WizardNewFileCreationPage](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Fwizard%2FWizardPage.html) class that is suitable

for my task.

It is supposed to be located in the package **org.eclipse.ui.dialogs**, however I can not find it.

Was it maybe moved in the latest version of eclipse to another location or removed completely?

I am using Kepler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WizardNewFileCreationPage` is in the `org.eclipse.ui.ide` plugin - so you will have add the plugin to your plugin's dependencies. As you said the package in `org.eclipse.ui.dialogs`

Comment: Thanks, it works now! Just for the future: How was I supposed to know it is in the _ide_ package or how can I find out?

Comment: In `Preferences > Plug-in Development` check  the `Include all plugin-ins from target in Java search`. With this checked `Navigate > Open Type...` will include all Eclipse classes so you can open the class (this will be the source if you have the Eclipse SDK installed). With the class open you can use the context menu `Show In > Package Explorer` to show which plugin it is in.